# Controlling bigger motors with an arduino board

Tags: motor, android

i am german and my english is not the best, anyway i hope you will understand my problem. 
At the moment i construct a little car with some friends. We have still completed the frame and now we think about controlling it in a electronic way. For example with a controller of a playstation or with our smartphones, however, it should be electronic, so i think about to do this with an arduino board.

We have two motors. One for the direction and the other one for the movement. 
The first has about 8 ampere and about 12 volt, the other has 800 watt, so around 40 ampere and 24 volt.

My question is, whether it is possible and if so how to control them (or one them) with an arduino board and what do i need in addition?

It would be great if you could help us :)

Comment: How much money do you have and how much are you ready to invest? It is totally possible.

Comment: Until 600 euro it is okay

Comment: Nice :)) In this case if yo do not have much experience in electronics i would suggest to buy ready to use DC motor controller. Like this http://www.pololu.com/product/1383 and control it with android

Comment: okay, thank you, i will try :)
if there are questions, could i ask you?

Comment: Sure why not. There will be about communication between arduino and android or any other device

Answer (score 2):

DC motors are typically driven with some sort of BJT/MOSFET solution that will be able to sink enough current to drive the motor because a microcontroller pin can only usually provide a few mA of power.  See [this link](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-spin-a-dc-motor-with-the-arduino.html) for info on basic microcontroller DC motor control.  If slow response is acceptable and only one level of power is required (i.e. no PWM) even power relays could be used to turn on off the motor.  Some applications could use this.  However, for your application, it sounds like you will want more responsive control over the motor and need a particularly high power MOSFET to properly drive your application as your motor is very high power.  Such FETS such as [these](http://www.digikey.com/product-highlights/us/en/ixys-gigamos-power-mosfets/332) could be used to properly control such a motor using the microcontroller.  Do note additional protection circuitry will be necessary and is probably the topic of another feed, but this would be a place to start if you wanted to build it from scratch.  Otherwise go with an over the shelf driver board which will probably have something like the link above used on it.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best ways to controll a motor is to look in to the motor shields from the arduino. You can buy seperate motor controllers with different throughput, some advanced with breaking and some without.

But motorshield is about the best way to get started.